# Any module that can translate Arabic to English in python/nltk?

Tags: python, nltk

Is there any module that can be used for translating Arabic to English in Python/NLTK ?

Answer (score 1):

You're probably best off looking at some of the online translation APIs, such as [Google Translate API](https://developers.google.com/translate/). I think that [SysTRAN](http://www.systran.co.uk/) also provides APIs, but I'm not sure if they support Arabic.

Google's API supports [bindings for Python](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/).

Either way, if there were a standalone solution, it probably wouldn't be very good and it would quickly outdate.

Comment: What exactly is not right? It is a paid solution, yes, but AFAIK Google Translate provides quite a decent job on major languages.

Comment: oh no am sorry I meant I try google translation and it not right...I am not looking for that thing that u talk about...I am looking for modul that can use in python...

Comment: See my update, Google DOES provide bindings for Python.

Comment: I am not sure if it support Arabic

Comment: حسنا، ترجمة غوغل يمكن أن تترجم إلى العربية، لذلك اعتقد انها ستعمل :)

Comment: I will give it a try.. (do you use it in python to write that?)

Comment: No, I used the website to translate that. It is quite unlikely that alanguage supported by their interface would not be supported by the API, though.

Comment: ok i will give it a try with python..thank you